# How should I delete, edit and add MySQL information with java and input?

Tags: java, mysql

This is where I tried to change the information from the user via text fields.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(inputID.getText());
String name = inputName.getText();
int age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
String adress = inputAdress.getText();
int income = Integer.parseInt(inputIncome.getText());
String sqlStmt = "update person set name = ?, godine = ?, adress = ?, income = ? where id = ?";
PreparedStatement prepStmt;
prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
prepStmt.setString(1, name);
prepStmt.setInt(2, age);
prepStmt.setString(3, adress);
prepStmt.setInt(4, income);
prepStmt.setInt(5, id);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

This is where I tried to delete the user by the input in id text field.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(inputID.getText());
String sqlStmt = "delete from person where id =  ?";
PreparedStatement prepStmt;
prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
prepStmt.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

This is where I tried to add a new user in the mysql database

```
String name = inputName.getText();
int age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
String adress = inputAdress.getText();
int income = Integer.parseInt(inputIncome.getText());
korisnik = new Korisnik(name,age,adress,income);
PreparedStatement prepStmt;
prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into person (name, age, adress, income) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
prepStmt.setString(1, korisnik.getName());
prepStmt.setInt(2, korisnik.getAge());
prepStmt.setString(3, korisnik.getAdress());
prepStmt.setInt(4, korisnik.getIncome());
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

None of these work and I don't know why and how to do it properly.

Here is the whole code.

```
package javaapplication7;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

klik klik = new klik();
Handler handler = new Handler();

Korisnik korisnik = null;
List<Korisnik> korisnik_lista = new ArrayList();

public Color silver = new Color(192, 192, 192);
public JPanel bar, prozor, prikaz;
public JLabel x, minimize, title, id, name, age, adress, income;
public JTextArea korisnici;
public JButton sviKorisnici, poGodinama, izmenaPoID, brisanjePoID, unosNovog;
public JTextField inputID, inputName, inputAge, inputAdress, inputIncome;
public JScrollPane scroll;

public Main() {
    bar = new JPanel();
    bar.setLayout(null);
    bar.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 25);
    bar.setBackground(silver);
    add(bar);

    prozor = new JPanel();
    prozor.setLayout(null);
    prozor.setBounds(0, 20, 600, 400);
    prozor.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(prozor);

    prikaz = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    prikaz.setLayout(null);
    prikaz.setBounds(10, 20, 380, 150);
    prozor.add(prikaz);

    x = new JLabel("X");
    x.setBounds(580, 0, 10, 20);
    x.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
    x.addMouseListener(klik);
    bar.add(x);

    minimize = new JLabel("_");
    minimize.setBounds(555, 0, 10, 15);
    minimize.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
    minimize.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    minimize.addMouseListener(klik);
    bar.add(minimize);

    title = new JLabel("Assignment");
    title.setBounds(20, 2, 100, 20);
    bar.add(title);

    sviKorisnici = new JButton("All Users");
    sviKorisnici.setBounds(420, 20, 120, 30);
    sviKorisnici.addActionListener(handler);
    prozor.add(sviKorisnici);

    poGodinama = new JButton("Find via Age");
    poGodinama.setBounds(420, 70, 120, 30);
    poGodinama.addActionListener(handler);
    prozor.add(poGodinama);

    izmenaPoID = new JButton("Change via ID");
    izmenaPoID.setBounds(420, 120, 120, 30);
    prozor.add(izmenaPoID);

    brisanjePoID = new JButton("Delete via ID");
    brisanjePoID.setBounds(420, 170, 120, 30);
    prozor.add(brisanjePoID);

    unosNovog = new JButton("Add New User");
    unosNovog.setBounds(420, 220, 120, 30);
    prozor.add(unosNovog);

    korisnici = new JTextArea();
    korisnici.setBounds(0, 0, 380, 150);
    korisnici.setEditable(false);
    prikaz.add(korisnici);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(korisnici);
    scroll.setBounds(0, 0, 380, 150);
    prikaz.add(scroll);

    id = new JLabel("ID:");
    id.setBounds(10, 200, 40, 20);
    prozor.add(id);

    inputID = new JTextField();
    inputID.setBounds(10, 220, 140, 20);
    prozor.add(inputID);

    name = new JLabel("Name:");
    name.setBounds(200, 200, 40, 20);
    prozor.add(name);

    inputName = new JTextField();
    inputName.setBounds(200, 220, 140, 20);
    prozor.add(inputName);

    age = new JLabel("Age:");
    age.setBounds(10, 250, 40, 20);
    prozor.add(age);

    inputAge = new JTextField();
    inputAge.setBounds(10, 270, 140, 20);
    prozor.add(inputAge);

    adress = new JLabel("Adress:");
    adress.setBounds(200, 250, 50, 20);
    prozor.add(adress);

    inputAdress = new JTextField();
    inputAdress.setBounds(200, 270, 140, 20);
    prozor.add(inputAdress);

    income = new JLabel("Income:");
    income.setBounds(10, 300, 140, 20);
    prozor.add(income);

    inputIncome = new JTextField();
    inputIncome.setBounds(10, 320, 140, 20);
    prozor.add(inputIncome);

    initComponents();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
}

class klik extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == x) {

            System.exit(0);

        } else if (e.getSource() == minimize) {

            setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);

        }

    }

}

class Handler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == sviKorisnici) {
            korisnik_lista.removeAll(korisnik_lista);
            korisnici.setText("");
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "traktor123");) {
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeQuery("select id, name, age, adress, income from person");
                ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    korisnik = new Korisnik(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("age"), rs.getString("adress"), rs.getInt("income"));
                    korisnik_lista.add(korisnik);
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        for (Korisnik kor : korisnik_lista) {
            korisnici.append(kor.toString());
            System.out.println(kor);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == poGodinama) {
            korisnik_lista.removeAll(korisnik_lista);
            korisnici.setText("");
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "traktor123");) {
                if(inputAge == null){
                    korisnici.setText("Nije unesen broj godina");
                }
                else{
                int godine = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
                String sqlStmt = "select * from person where age =  ?";
                PreparedStatement prepStmt;
                prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
                prepStmt.setInt(1, godine);
                ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    korisnik = new Korisnik(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("age"), rs.getString("adress"), rs.getInt("income"));
                    korisnik_lista.add(korisnik);
                }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
            for (Korisnik kor : korisnik_lista) {
                korisnici.append(kor.toString());
                System.out.println(kor);
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == izmenaPoID) {
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "traktor123");) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(inputID.getText());
                String name = inputName.getText();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
                String adress = inputAdress.getText();
                int income = Integer.parseInt(inputIncome.getText());
                String sqlStmt = "update person set name = ?, godine = ?, adress = ?, income = ? where id = ?";
                PreparedStatement prepStmt;
                prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
                prepStmt.setString(1, name);
                prepStmt.setInt(2, age);
                prepStmt.setString(3, adress);
                prepStmt.setInt(4, income);
                prepStmt.setInt(5, id);
                prepStmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
        if (e.getSource() == brisanjePoID) {
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "traktor123");) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(inputID.getText());
                String sqlStmt = "delete from person where id =  ?";
                PreparedStatement prepStmt;
                prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
                prepStmt.setInt(1, id);
                prepStmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == unosNovog) {
            try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "traktor123");) {
                String name = inputName.getText();
                int age = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
                String adress = inputAdress.getText();
                int income = Integer.parseInt(inputIncome.getText());
                korisnik = new Korisnik(name,age,adress,income);
                PreparedStatement prepStmt;
                prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into person (name, age, adress, income) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                prepStmt.setString(1, korisnik.getName());
                prepStmt.setInt(2, korisnik.getAge());
                prepStmt.setString(3, korisnik.getAdress());
                prepStmt.setInt(4, korisnik.getIncome());
                prepStmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in database connection: \n" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

void initComponents() {
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(600, 400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the error please ?

Comment: There are no errors in the code, just doesn't work

Comment: few chance it "doesn't work" without throwing an error

Comment: Try to use try catch block and debug mode. You must use `executeUpdate()` and not `executeQuery()` according to [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I'm using the try and catch for connecting to the database when the button for deleting, editing and adding new users is clicked. When I change it to executeUpdate the error is incompatible type; int cannot be converted to ResultSet

Answer (score 1):

`executeQuery()`
Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

`executeUpdate()`
Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

In your case use `executeUpdate()` see the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I changed it to prepStmt.executeUpdate(); instead of ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery(); and still doesn't work

Comment: May be you don't use the auto-commit mode try to add `conn.commit();` to commit all changes

Comment: this is so strange. there is no logs, no traces of erros ? nothing all yor code is executed without any problèmes ?

Comment: Yes, I'll put the whole code, maybe it's something else